# How can I create a mirror and add packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, mirrors, apt-mirror

So I would like to create a Debian and Ubuntu mirror and add some packages that I cannot find or that are very outdated to it so when I install Linux I can just add this repo and install everything we usually use. (And public could too)

I know my way around nginx, but the repo part of that, no idea.

apt-mirror is quite easy but can I add a completely different repo to it and how can I add my own packages (rethinkdb for exemple) and sign those?

I found many guides (very outdated).

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I forgot to ask how can I ignore some packages that I don't want mirrored. Like all the basic small packages that are everywhere already - I would like to mirror only some packages - or excluse multiple packages.